# Setting a value post update with the `findOneAndUpdate` Mongoose hook

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use the `findOneAndUpdate` hook with Mongoose (discussed in detail [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964)), although I'm having some problems trying to set a value post update.

For example:

```
MySchema.findOneAndUpdate({_id: fj394hri3hfj}, {$push: {comments: myNewComment}})
```

Will trigger the following hook:

```
MySchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(result) {
    this.update({}, { totalNumberOfComments: result.comments.length });
});
```

Although, the hook will `$push` to `comments` the `myNewComment` again, therefore making a duplicate entry.

I use `this.update({}, {....})` instead of `this.findOneAndUpdate({}, {....})` within the hook so that the `post` hook is not called infinitely.

The `totalNumberOfComments` is set perfectly to the length of `comments.length`.

So it seems as if `this.update({}, {....})` is just pushing more update fields to the already existing update fields on `this`.

How can I just set `totalNumberOfComments` within my hook instead of re-pushing to comments again?

Comment: Are you sure post `findOneAndUpdate` hook is getting called in your case?

Comment: Well yes, that's why it's creating duplicates, because it's called both on my `findOneAndUpdate` call and then once again inside the hook. I also did a `console.log(this)` inside the hook and it logged successfully. The problem is, `this` still holds the `$push: {comments: myNewComment}` update, and the hook is just pushing a `$set` update to it too, hence having it `$push` twice.

Comment: Ok. Is it really necessary to use post hook? You can just do `find` and `save` instead.

Comment: If you still want to use post hook, try replacing code within your hook with `this.totalNumberOfComments = this.result.comments.length; this.save(function(err){ console.log("Document Updated");})`. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: @user2235057 Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't 'save' create a new document with a new ID rather than updating the existing one?

Comment: No it does not if you update the document returned by find and call save on same. I am talking about first approach mentioned here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html.

Comment: Added code in answer for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be in update query you wrote in post `findOneAndUpdate` hook. Try replacing it with,

```
MySchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(result) {
    this.totalNumberOfComments = this.result.comments.length;
    this.save(function(err) {
       if(!err) {
          console.log("Document Updated");
       }
    });
});
```

And hopefully it should work.

I would also suggest, using `find` and `save` for updating document instead of `findOneAndUpdate` and its post hook.

---

**Edit:**

In case you need to use `find` and `save`, you can replace above code with:

```
MySchema.findById(fj394hri3hfj, function(err, doc){

    doc.comments.push(myNewComment);
    doc.totalNumberOfComments += 1;
    doc.save(function(err){

       console.log("Document Updated");       
    }); 
});
```

and it should work.

Comment: Decided to go with your second option of just setting the comments length during the save. Probably better to do it that way incase I want to allow comment deletion in the future too. Will award bounty in 12 hours. Thanks!

Comment: careful of using `.save()` in this way, it is unsafe in terms of concurrency.